# How can we merge result of two instagram API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, instagram, instafeedjs

I need to show Instagram Image on a web page based on UserName and Tags

After looking around and searching for such api i couldn't find  which can allow me following

1. Show Images based on User Account +
2. Show images based on Tags (Single or multiple)

I can use two separate API calls to show both results separately but i am not sure how to merge both results and show them as one based on latest images.

Example based on angular and instgram API
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdrBMQ?editors=001

I also looked at `instafeedjs` It allows to show images based on UserAccount and Filter same result based on Tags
Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqpWER?editors=001

Any such example where i can show images from User Account + Any Tag(s).

Comment: 'show them as one': like merge them into an array and display with ng-repeat? If you need to wait until both api calls are done, you could use $q.all: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q (end of the page)

Comment: Thanks you, I will try as i am not a scripting guys let me try to see how far i can go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging shouldn't be too hard:

```
var byUserUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/828057799/media/recent/?client_id=5e7cb176cc4340c09124d9f50733f34f&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

//Search by tag
var byTagUrl ='https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/flight/media/recent/?client_id=5e7cb176cc4340c09124d9f50733f34f&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

app.controller("InstagramCtrl", function InstagramCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.photos = [];
  $http.jsonp(byUserUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.photos = $scope.photos.concat(data.data);
  });
  $http.jsonp(byTagUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.photos = $scope.photos.concat(data.data);
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbpwmm

Comment: Thanks You this works as i wanted. Just want to know how is it sorting images is it by latest or ?. I also added second tag to it..

Comment: in your html: `li(ng-repeat='photo in photos | orderBy: created_time')`

Comment: Thank you, can we give order like ASC or DESC

Comment: I think the default is ascending. If you want descending order, use `li(ng-repeat='photo in photos | orderBy: "-created_time"')`